# reshape datas group by in r

Tags: r, group-by, reshape

I would like to reshape my datas

```
 DateDaily      Symbol      SIZE1           SIZE2     SIZE3
1  2018-01-02          A  152291500       157400750 154846125
2  2018-01-02          A  120044425       205589050 162816738
3  2018-01-02          A  123262750       224815138 174038944
4  2018-01-02          A  124282350       197877388 161079869
5  2018-01-02          B  119276200       173101600 146188900
6  2018-01-02          B  104249638       193376038 148812838
7  2018-01-02          B  101319438       145487563 123403500
8  2018-01-02          C    8088975        10159738   9124356
9  2018-01-02          C  164439888       143390813 153915350
```

How can I reshape to have only one date and group by the average of the datas SIZE1, SIZE1, SIZE2

```
 DateDaily      Symbol   SIZE1     SIZE2    SIZE3
1  2018-01-02        A    mean       mean      mean 
5  2018-01-02        B    mean       mean      mean
8  2018-01-02        C    mean       mean      mean
```

...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% group_by(DateDaily, Symbol) %>% 
         summarise_if(is.numeric,mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```